# Wallpaper chooser tutorial?

Tags: android

I am looking to develop a simple application that contains a Gallery View and an Image View and tapping on the imageview will set the image as the wallpaper.

I have tried following several tutorials, but the images that I want to use are quite large and always get an OOM exception.  I have tried scaling them with bitmapfactory before setting them, but I can't get it to work correctly. What I have so far is below.  I didn't think this would be so difficult.. Can anyone help me determine what I need to do next?

Thanks!

```
package org.androidpeople.gallery;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class GalleryExample extends Activity {

private Gallery gallery;
private ImageView imgView;
int position;
private Integer[] Imgid = { R.drawable.hm001, R.drawable.hm002, R.drawable.hm003,
        R.drawable.hm004, R.drawable.hm005, R.drawable.hm006,             R.drawable.hm007 };

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle home) {
    super.onCreate(home);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    position = 0;
    imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
    imgView.setImageResource(Imgid[0]);
    gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.examplegallery);
    gallery.setAdapter(new AddImgAdp(this));
    Bitmap bm;
 bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 213, 189, true);





    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,
                long id) {

            imgView.setImageResource(Imgid[position]);
            GalleryExample.this.position = position;
        }
    });


    imgView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    GalleryExample.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Confirmation");
            alertDialog
                    .setMessage("Do you want to set this image as wallaper?");
            alertDialog.setButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {

                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                                    getResources(), Imgid[position]);
                            try {
                                GalleryExample.this.setWallpaper(bitmap);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Log.d("Gallery Example", "Image setted.");

                        }
                    });

            alertDialog.show();
            return true;
        }
    });

}

public class AddImgAdp extends BaseAdapter {
    int GalItemBg;
    private Context cont;

    public AddImgAdp(Context c) {
        cont = c;
        TypedArray typArray = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.GalleryTheme);
        GalItemBg = typArray.getResourceId(
                R.styleable.GalleryTheme_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        typArray.recycle();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return Imgid.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(cont);

        imgView.setImageResource(Imgid[position]);
        imgView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(80, 70));
        imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imgView.setBackgroundResource(GalItemBg);

        return imgView;
    }
    Bitmap ShrinkBitmap(Resource, int width, int height){

         BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(null, String, bmpFactoryOptions);

            int heightRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight/(float)height);
            int widthRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth/(float)width);

            if (heightRatio > 1 || widthRatio > 1)
            {
             if (heightRatio > widthRatio)
             {
              bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = heightRatio;
             } else {
              bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = widthRatio; 
             }
            }

            bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmpFactoryOptions);
         return bitmap;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just put `bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 213, 189, true);` below that

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), Imgid[position]);
```

I mean the final view should be;

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), Imgid[position]); 
    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 213, 189, true);
```